# Display values not percentage on google pie chart legend

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have the following code to make a google pie chart.

Currently, this code displays the legend, but with a percentage of the tasks, rather than the number as displayed on the actual pie chart.

Is there a way to make the legend show the number of tasks and the pie chart not to show any number?

```
function init() {
 google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages:["corechart"], 
 callback: 'drawChart' });
}
// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Tasks', 'Completed'],
     ['Morning',     28],
     ['Afternoon',      0],
     ['Evening',  0],
     ['Night',  161]
 ]);

// Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
var options = {
    width: 900,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Total = 189',
    pieHole: 0.5,
    colors: ['#008000', '#ffbf00', '#FF0000','#4E6282'],
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    sliceVisibilityThreshold :0,
    fontSize: 17,
    legend: {
        position: 'labeled'
    },
    };

// Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
 var chart = new 
 google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
 chart.draw(data, options);
}
```